# Check if Particular ViewController is there in Navigation Stack more than once

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am working on iOS Application in which I want to check whether the Particular ViewController appears more than once in Navigation Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.navigationController.viewControllers` returns all view controllers in stack. do like

```
@interface ViewController () {
    // create the one global int for get the count of VC.
    int myVar;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myVar = 0;
    for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
        // check your VC is available or not in using isKindOfClass
        if ([vc isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]]) {
            myVar +=  1;
        }
    }

    if (myVar > 1){
        // available
    }
}
```

Comment: I need your help.

Comment: @Niharika - yes ,

Comment: is there a way to connect. I am unable to create a Chat room.!

Comment: @Niharika - for private chat, we need to ping here long time

Comment: @Niharika - proceed here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173036/discussion-between-niharika-and-anbu-karthik).